# Python JSON -> CSV different headers

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a json file that is like so:

```
{"16CD7631-0ED0-4DA0-8D3B-8BBB41992EED": {"id": "16CD7631-0ED0-4DA0-8D3B-8BBB41992EED", "longitude": "-122.406417", "reportType": "Other", "latitude": "37.785834"}, "91CA4A9C-9A48-41A2-8453-07CBC8DC723E": {"id": "91CA4A9C-9A48-41A2-8453-07CBC8DC723E", "longitude": "-1.1932383", "reportType": "Street Obstruction", "latitude": "45.8827419"}}
```

The goal is to get this to turn into a csv file like so:

```
id,longitude,reportType,latitude
16CD7631-0ED0-4DA0-8D3B-8BBB41992EED,-122.406417,Other,37.785834
91CA4A9C-9A48-41A2-8453-07CBC8DC723E,-1.1932383,Street Obstruction,45.8827419
```

I tried just doing

```
with open('sample.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
        df = pd.read_json(inputfile)

df.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

But because the name of each document was named its id, I get incorrect output. What is the best way to achieve my goal? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Try this :

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('sample.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
    data = json.load(inputfile)
    df = pd.json_normalize(data[k] for k in data.keys())
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df.to_string())

                                     id    longitude          reportType    latitude
0  16CD7631-0ED0-4DA0-8D3B-8BBB41992EED  -122.406417               Other   37.785834
1  91CA4A9C-9A48-41A2-8453-07CBC8DC723E   -1.1932383  Street Obstruction  45.8827419
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, what should data point to?

Comment: Hello, sorry to keep bugging you, is there way to remove the first column (0 and 1) from this? Thank you

Comment: If you're saving the dataframe in a `.csv`, you can use `index=False` like this : `df.to_csv("outputfile.csv", index=False)`.

Comment: Or if you wanna just print the dataframe, use `print(df.to_string(index=False))`.